# iterating over lists finding standard deviation of each point

Tags: python, list, loops, python-2.x, standard-deviation

I have this section of code that is supposed to find the standard deviation of each number in A, where A is a list of lists consisting of 7 values.

```
def sigma(A):
    diff = 0
    positives = [b for b in A if b >= 0]
    if positives:
        mean = sum(positives) / len(positives)
        for i in positives:  
            diff = ((sum([abs(i - mean)**2 for i in positives]))/(len(positives)))**(0.5)
            return diff
    else:
        return 0

    G = map(sigma, zip(*A))
    print G
```

this correctly gives me the standard deviation for the first list of 7 numbers but shouldn't `map(sigma, zip(*A))` make it iterate over all the lists? I have also tried `[sigma(A) for col in xrange(len(rows[0]))]` but that did not work either. Ideally the standard deviations would also be saved as a list of lists of seven. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
this is the code that I have now;

```
def sigma(A):
    diff = 0
    positives = [b for b in A if b >= 0]
    if positives:
        mean = sum(positives) / len(positives)
        diff += ((sum([abs(i - mean)**2 for i in positives]))/(len(positives)))**(0.5)
        for i in positives:
            if (abs(i - mean)) > (diff*3):
                return -9999.00
            else:
                return i

    else:
        return -9999.00

G = map(sigma, zip(*A))
print G
```

it does all the things I want it to do however when I run it this way it only outputs for the first row. If the 'return' statements are replace with 'print' and `print G` is removed the outputs I want for all the rows are printed. How can I store all these values in a list? I'm assuming it's this line `G = map(sigma, zip(*A))` that's the problem. I tried changing it to `G = map(sigma, A)` however this only gives me the numbers for the first column.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what "all lists"? Short answer is "yes", but it's very possible for `A` to be structured in a way that makes this break. So, you need to post some more information, specifically answer "what does `A` look like?" and "what error do you get?"

Comment: "but that did not work either". Of course, because software has only one failure mode, we all know exactly what that means.

Comment: A looks like `[[-9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0], [-9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0], [0.040896, 0.018690, 0.005620, -9999.0, 0.038722, 0.018323, -9999.0], [0.039443, 0.017517, 0.003460, -9999.0, 0.035526, 0.011692, -9999.0], [-9999.0, 0.017963, 0.005264, -9999.0, 0.03788, 0.014316, -9999.0]]` so "all lists" would be the 5 sets of 7 numbers. I'm not getting an error, I'm just not getting all the information I want (all 5 iterations) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`positives = [b for b in A if b >= 0]` doesn't do what you think it does. `b` would be a list of 7 elements, how can a list of 7 elements be greater than 0?

numpy makes this easy:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
A = [[-9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0],
    [-9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0],
    [0.040896, 0.018690, 0.005620, -9999.0, 0.038722, 0.018323, -9999.0],
    [0.039443, 0.017517, 0.003460, -9999.0, 0.035526, 0.011692, -9999.0],
    [-9999.0, 0.017963, 0.005264, -9999.0, 0.03788, 0.014316, -9999.0]]
A = np.array(A)

sigmas = []
for b in A:
    bmask=ma.masked_array(b,mask=np.greater_equal(b,0))
    b=b[bmask.mask]
    print b
    sigmas.append(np.std(b))
```

gives

```
[]
[]
[ 0.040896  0.01869   0.00562   0.038722  0.018323]
[ 0.039443  0.017517  0.00346   0.035526  0.011692]
[ 0.017963  0.005264  0.03788   0.014316]

>>> sigmas
[0.0, 0.0, 0.013412289355661845, 0.013828802328473713, 0.011917047544903896]
```

edit: in response to comment

```
>>> A=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[2,-3,4,-3,2,1,-9]]
>>> [b for b in A if b>=0]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, -3, 4, -3, 2, 1, -9]]
```

Python doesn't give you an error, but it is not comparing the elements in `b` to `0`, it is only comparing `b`, which is evaluated as a boolean.

Here you can see explicitly what is happening:

```
>>> bool(b)
True
>>> True >= 0
True
```

For every list of 7 numbers `b` in A you are just doing `True >= 0`, which is always `True`.

**edit2**: I'm an idiot and see now you were trying to use map and the problem I was talking about would be avoided.  Just change `G = map(sigma, zip(*A))` to `G = map(sigma, A)`

**edit3:**: you were returning `i` instead of `diff`.  here is the code:

```
def sigma(A):
    positives = [b for b in A if b >= 0]
    if positives:
        mean = sum(positives) / len(positives)
        diff = ((sum([abs(i - mean)**2 for i in positives]))/(len(positives)))**(0.5)
        for i in positives:
            if (abs(i - mean)) > (diff*3):
                return -9999.00
        return diff
    else:
        return -9999.00

A = [[-9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0],
    [-9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0],
    [0.040896, 0.018690, 0.005620, -9999.0, 0.038722, 0.018323, -9999.0],
    [0.039443, 0.017517, 0.003460, -9999.0, 0.035526, 0.011692, -9999.0],
    [-9999.0, 0.017963, 0.005264, -9999.0, 0.03788, 0.014316, -9999.0]]

G = map(sigma, A)
```

which gives:

```
>>> G
[-9999.0, -9999.0, 0.013412289355661845, 0.013828802328473713, 0.011917047544903896]
```

**edit4**:  clarified problem

```
def sigma(A):
    positives = [b for b in A if b >= 0]
    sq_err=[]
    if positives:
        mean = sum(positives) / len(positives)
        diff = ((sum([abs(i - mean)**2 for i in positives]))/(len(positives)))**(0.5)
        for i in positives:
            if (abs(i - mean)) > (diff*3):
                sq_err.append(-9999.00)
            else:
                sq_err.append(i)
    else:
        return [-9999.00]
    return sq_err

A = [[-9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0],
    [-9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0],
    [0.040896, 0.018690, 0.005620, -9999.0, 0.038722, 0.018323, -9999.0],
    [0.039443, 0.017517, 0.003460, -9999.0, 0.035526, 0.011692, -9999.0],
    [-9999.0, 0.017963, 0.005264, -9999.0, 0.03788, 0.014316, -9999.0]]

G = map(sigma, A)
```

gives

```
>>> G
[[-9999.0], [-9999.0], [0.040896, 0.01869, 0.00562, 0.038722, 0.018323], [0.039443, 0.017517, 0.00346, 0.035526, 0.011692], [0.017963, 0.005264, 0.03788, 0.014316]]
```

Comment: so I'm using `positives = [b for b in A if b >= 0]` to give me only the positive numbers in each row of A and it seems to be working. Also if possible I would like to know what is wrong with my code because now it seems to do everything I want but when I call the function I only get the first row back

Comment: `>>> A=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[2,-3,4,-3,2,1,-9]]`
`>>> [b for b in A if b>=0]`
`[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, -3, 4, -3, 2, 1, -9]]`

Comment: print A= `[[-9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0], [-9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0, -9999.0], [0.040896, 0.018690, 0.005620, -9999.0, 0.038722, 0.018323, -9999.0], [0.039443, 0.017517, 0.003460, -9999.0, 0.035526, 0.011692, -9999.0], [-9999.0, 0.017963, 0.005264, -9999.0, 0.037885, 0.014316, -9999.0]]`
but when I do print positives=`[0.040896, 0.039443]
[0.018690, 0.017517, 0.017963]
[0.005620, 0.003460, 0.005264]
[0.038722, 0.035526, 0.037885]
[0.018323, 0.011692, 0.014316]` hmmm?

Comment: No problem! Thanks for sticking this out with me haha. I did try map(sigma, A) and then I only get the first number from each row

Comment: but G is still a list of 7 numbers, it should be 5 lists of 7 numbers

Comment: Oh. I think there's some terminology confusion here.  `sigma`, i.e. the standard deviation is a property of a *list* of numbers.  There is no such thing as a standard deviation of just a number.  You seem to just want the squared error for each member of the list, if it's less than three times the standard deviation.  right?

Comment: true. the functions purpose is to find the sigma of each row, and compare the difference of each number to the mean throwing out those that differ by more then 3 sigma